# Can you get the MaxEnvelopeSizeKb without needing to be an admin?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to get the current MaxEnvelopeSizeKb without needing to be in an administrative shell in PowerShell.

```
Get-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizeKb
```

As an admin, it works.  But if not in an admin shell:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizeKb' because it does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You *can*, but only if a *custom value* `MaxEnvelopeSizeKb` has been configured - you won't be able to see the *default* value - but you may be comfortable *assuming* what it is**; since at least Window 7 and as of Windows 10 version 1909, it is `500` (KB), but conceivably it could change in the future.

```
# Use only if running as admin ISN'T an option.
# If it IS, use the following instead:
#    $maxEnvSize = [uint64] (Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizekb).Value
# Note: The snippet is PSv5+, due to use Get-ItemPropertyValue
# (solution for earlier versions is possible).

$maxEnvSize = try {
  Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Stop HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Client maxEnvelopeSize
} catch {
  500 # default value since Windows 7
}
```

---

**To see the default value, and to see and modify all settings, you *do* need elevation (administrative privileges)**, which applies to:

- access to the `WSMAN:` drive in PowerShell
- use of `winrm get winrm/config` utility
- access to the subkeys of the following registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN
```

However, subkeys `Client` and `WinRS` are the *exception* in that they can be accessed even without elevation, which the approach above relies on: the `MaxEnvelopeSizeKb` value is stored in the `Client` subkey, albeit with a slightly different name: `maxEnvelopeSize`

---

As an aside: It is unfortunate that the error message mistakenly suggests that the path doesn't *exist* instead of telling you about the *permissions* problem.